# rm -rf failing if deleting in parallel

Tags: files, rm, concurrency

`rm -rf` will fail if something tries to delete the same file tree (I think because `rm` enumerates the files first, then deletes).

A simple test:

```
# Terminal 1
for i in `seq 1 1000`; do mkdir -p /tmp/dirtest/$i; done

# Now at the same time in terminal 1 and 2
rm -rf /tmp/dirtest
```

There will be some output into stderr, e.g.:

```
...
rm: cannot remove directory `/tmp/dirtest/294': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove directory `/tmp/dirtest/297': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove directory `/tmp/dirtest/304': No such file or directory
```

I can ignore all the stderr output by redirecting it to `/dev/null`, but removing of `/tmp/dirtest` actually fails! After both commands are finished, `/tmp/dirtest` is still there.

How can I make `rm` delete the directory tree properly and really ignore all the errors?

Comment: why are you trying to delete in 2 terminals at once? it shouldn't be any faster, the filesystem nor hard drive is designed for that. I don't know if it will work but maybe `find /tmp/dirtest -delete` would

Comment: @xenoterracide I'm not doing it deliberately, it's an artifact of our build system. `rm`-ing with two terminals is just an easy-to-reproduce artificial scenario.

Comment: you should state that in your question. That's a point that makes the problem interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Nasty. But in a sense, you're looking for trouble when two concurrent processes are manipulating a directory tree. Unix provides primitives for atomic manipulation of a single file, but not for whole directory trees.

A simple workaround would be for your script to rename the directory before removing it. Since your use case has cooperating scripts, it's ok for the new name to be predictable.

```
mv /build/tree /build/tree.rm.$$
mkdir /build/tree
rm -rf /build/tree.rm.$$
```

Maybe you can even do the `rm` in the background later, while your build performs some CPU-bound tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how the build system ended up like this. Are you able to change it? At a minimum, you can create a flag that lets the scripts know the other one is already doing the job...

```
mkdir /tmp/flag.rmdirtest && rm -rf /tmp/dirtest && rmdir /tmp/flag.rmdirtest
```

It would be better to re-architect the thing so that this isn't necessary.